# Error installing kdtree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, bundle, kdtree

When I tried running my Ruby code with bundle install, I encountered this error: `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

I tried running `gem install kdtree` and `gem install kdtree -v '0.3'` but it throws me the same error as well. Now I am unable to run my Ruby code. Any ideas on how to resolve this. I am running on Windows machine btw. Here's the full error log:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating kdtree-i386-mingw32.def
compiling kdtree.c
kdtree.c: In function 'kdtree_nearest0':
kdtree.c:221:13: error: expected identifier or '(' before ',' token
kdtree.c:237:14: error: expected expression before '=' token
kdtree.c:237:29: error: expected expression before '=' token
kdtree.c:239:14: error: expected expression before '=' token
kdtree.c:239:30: error: expected expression before '=' token
kdtree.c:241:34: error: expected expression before ',' token
kdtree.c:241:34: error: too few arguments to function 'kdtree_nearest0'
kdtree.c:217:13: note: declared here
kdtree.c:243:37: error: expected expression before ',' token
kdtree.c:243:37: error: too few arguments to function 'kdtree_nearest0'
kdtree.c:217:13: note: declared here
kdtree.c: In function 'kdtree_nearestk0':
kdtree.c:313:13: error: expected identifier or '(' before ',' token
kdtree.c:330:14: error: expected expression before '=' token
kdtree.c:330:29: error: expected expression before '=' token
kdtree.c:332:14: error: expected expression before '=' token
kdtree.c:332:30: error: expected expression before '=' token
kdtree.c:334:35: error: expected expression before ',' token
kdtree.c:334:35: error: too few arguments to function 'kdtree_nearestk0'
kdtree.c:309:13: note: declared here
kdtree.c:336:38: error: expected expression before ',' token
kdtree.c:336:38: error: too few arguments to function 'kdtree_nearestk0'
kdtree.c:309:13: note: declared here
kdtree.c: In function 'kdtree_persist':
kdtree.c:409:11: warning: unused variable 'str' [-Wunused-variable]
make: *** [kdtree.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```